# i have an error on NSLog why it's not working?

Tags: xcode

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{


    [connection release];
    [receivedData release];
    [theRequest release];

    //NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@"),[error localizedDescription],[[error userInfo]objectForKey:NSErrorFailingURLStringKey]);

    if(errorCallback)
    {
        [delegate performSelector:errorCallback withObject:error];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@"),[error localizedDescription],[[error userInfo]objectForKey:NSErrorFailingURLStringKey]);
```

**Should be**

```
//NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",[error localizedDescription],[[error userInfo]objectForKey:NSErrorFailingURLStringKey]);
```